# How to read binary data from Gstreamer child process on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, binary, pipe, gstreamer

```
f = os.popen("gst-launch -q whateversrc ! ... ! fdsink")
f.read(1024);
```

Works just fine on GNU/Linux, but leads to \x0d\x0a instead of each \x0a of Windows. How to fix?

I also tried just `gst-launch -q ..... ! matroskamux  streamable=true ! fdsink > qqq3.mkv` in console and qqq3.mkv also garbled. `gst-launch -q filesrc location=file ! fdsink > file2` also converts to CRLF.

What to do? Gstreamer build for windows does not have tcp{server,client}sink...

May be there's a way to just turn off that LF->CRLF conversion globally in Windows (or for a given application)?

Comment: You should really consider using the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) rather than `os.popen`. Also, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: "Python 2.6.5" in Cygwin

Comment: Have you tried specifying a mode on the `os.popen` call? For example, you could try either `os.popen("gst-launch ...", "r")` or `os.popen("gst-launch ...", "rb")`. The former should be the default behaviour, while the latter explicitly specifies reading binary data.

Comment: Tried also `subprocess.Popen(cam_cmd, shell=True, bufsize=1024, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout` - the same issue

Comment: srgerg, Tried "rb" - the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you shouldn't use `shell=True` with `subprocess.Popen()`.

Using Windows 7 64-bit, with Python running in Cygwin, I wrote this simple test program:

```
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen(['cat', 'junk.bin'], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.
PIPE)
stdin, stdout = p.communicate()

with open('junk1.bin', "wb") as f:
    f.write(stdin)
```

For me, `junk1.bin` is a byte-perfect copy of `junk.bin`, so I am not seeing the `"\n"` -> `"\r\n"` transformation that is happening to you.

EDIT: I found a web page that looks useful:

http://blog.rubypdf.com/2009/11/03/how-to-let-python-send-binary-data-to-stdout-under-windows/

```
import sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
    import os, msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
```

If the child process inherits the binary mode settings of the stdin and stdout file handles of the parent process, then maybe running the above code in your Python parent process would help?

If it doesn't, then try the same trick but on the `stdin` and `stdout` handles in the object returned by `subprocess.Popen()`.  In my above code, I bind that object to the name `p` so they would be `p.stdin` and `p.stdout`:

```
msvcrt.setmode(p.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
msvcrt.setmode(p.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(["gst-launch", "-q", "whateversrc", ........., "!",  "matroskamux",  "streamable=true", "!", "fdsink"], shell=False, bufsize=1024, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout` - the same problems

Comment: It's very unlikely that "fdsink" Gstreamer module does "_binmode(... O_BINARY)" (or other Windows-specific things). How to force other process to have all handles binary by default?

Comment: I'm curious to know whether the `msvcrt.setmode()` stuff helps you.  Please post an update when you try it!

Comment: Do you think it will help if data gets broken before it gets into my program? Will it set binary more both for my python process and for child process as well? (Lost hope in getting it working without manual compilation of Gstreamer for windows)

Comment: I don't know for sure how it works, but it is at least possible that if you set the binary mode on the file handles of the parent process, that the subsequent child processes will inherit the setting, and thus all the child processes will use binary mode file handles to communicate.  I'm sorry but I don't have GStreamer for Windows installed and I can't run a test for this.